# Is the DeLorean locked to the Pacific Time Zone?

Tags: time-travel, back-to-the-future

Suppose the Doc or Marty drove the DeLorean to Arizona, which is one hour ahead of California, and then set the time coordinates for one hour ahead. Would the car realise that the local time had changed and adjust accordingly (as a 2017 mobile phone would by picking up the time from the cell network) or would it still show the present time on its display as the time in Hill Valley (as the clock on the dash of an ordinary car would)? And would the time jump result in the car travelling two hours ahead, one hour ahead or no time at all?

Comment: Very good article on the interface of the time control in the DeLorean : https://scifiinterfaces.wordpress.com/2015/10/21/time-circuits/

Comment: Oh! And how about DST?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the DeLorean only moves in *time*, not in *space*.

Doc says there are three lines :

[image]

- Where you are going
- Where you are
- Where you came from

I suppose the "where you are" **should** automatically adapt to the local zone when you travel through states, so every destination date modification should take account of that previously modified timezone.

I'm French so I don't know how people managed timezones during trips in USA in 1985 so I don't know if this sort of automation was possible. Maybe the driver must had to change the time on the time circuits manually...

Comment: Yes, it's all relative . . .

Comment: WRT your last comment: I guess they did have to adjust their watches manually; same as travelling between, say Spain and Portugal. The technology to change clocks automatically was available, but it was far too expensive for ordinary people to have access to.